# Boolean pandas series contains NA but only on real, not test, data

Tags: pandas

Some code has stopped working and I am confused. I have not managed to reproduce the behavior on test data. I want a column containing a Boolean to say if the next user is the same as the current row's user. Here is how it works on my test data.

```python
data = {'user': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'time': [1, 3, 7, 2, 8, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df['match'] = df['user'].shift(-1) == df['user']
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'match']
```

> False

I.e. the last row's user does not match the user of the non-existent next row and so the value of 'match' is False

If I run 'identical' code on my real data

```python
events['match'] = events['user_id'].shift(-1) == events['user_id']
events.loc[events.index[-1], 'match']
```

> <NA>

Why? There are no NaN values in my data's 'user_id' column, so I cannot see how that NaN could arise in my data but not in the simple test data?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same version of pandas in both cases? pandas < 1 uses np.nan for NaN  values, and (np.nan == 1) returns False, but in pandas==1.0, there is a new pd.NA type and (pd.NA == 1) returns pd.NA (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#propagation-in-arithmetic-and-comparison-operations)

Comment: I'm testing both in the same notebook, so it must be the same. But that is an interesting 'gotcha'